# What does "r8169: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control" really mean?

Tags: boot, networking

I have this message in syslog and dmesg output:

```
r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
```

Is it a configuration problem or hardware issue?

Comment: I enabled ASPM from bios and the error is gone. No need to install anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

r8169 is the name of a module for the Realtek RTL8169 Network Interface Controller which may be included in your `/etc/modules` file. ASPM stands for Active State Power Management. ASPM enablement can be configured by BIOS or by an OS.

To run the aspm test in the Firmware Test Suite (fwts), open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install fwts  
sudo fwts aspm
```

To show the verbose results of `sudo fwts aspm` run the following command:

```
cat results.log
```

This test checks the enablement method in ACPI table and verifies the correctness of the ASPM configuration. Visit the [Ubuntu Firmware Test Suite/Reference/aspm wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FirmwareTestSuite/Reference/aspm) for information about how to evaluate the results of running `sudo fwts aspm` .

Comment: Obviously, I didn't disable L0s or L1s. Do you know how can I enable them?

Comment: `lshw` says it's `RTL8111/8168/8411` (and I'm lazy to check the box) if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, it does make a difference. Mine is also RTL8111/8168/8411! Also could you please run `sudo lshw -C network`, and comment about all the capabilities that appear after where it says: `capabilities:`. In particular whether it says `pm`, `aspm` or both `pm` and `aspm` . Also please check in the `/etc/modules` file, and comment about what are all the kernel modules that it says are loaded at boot time.

Comment: `capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation` (no aspm). Modules: `lp coretemp f71882fg`

Comment: You have the same `RTL8111/8168/8411` and also the same list of network capabilities as my desktop. Since it is a desktop and not a laptop I don't need a power-saving application. However if you want to install a power-saving application on a laptop to increase the battery life, there are answers to that question here on askubuntu. I use laptop-mode-tools from the Ubuntu Software Center on my laptop. TLP from the ppa:linrunner/tlp PPA is said to be stronger, but less stable on some laptop models.

Comment: Did anybody mange to make ASPM working for RTL8111 on desktop? Perhaps that does not save much but according to [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagementASPM) it might be few Wh which is worth trying... I have the same chip and `lshw` does not report `aspm` in `capabilities`.

Comment: sudo fwts aspm
Running 1 tests, results appended to results.log
Test: PCIe ASPM test.                                                       
  PCIe ASPM ACPI test.                                                         
  PCIe ASPM registers test. 6 passed ... 6 warnings!!!   1st/ Thanks, Karel! and 2nd/ IT IS FINALLY GREAT to see the term ACPI and Linux/Ubuntu in a semi-positive light!!  ... 3/  I am ecstatic something actually passed in my Ubuntu/ACPI, but how do I see what passed, and what failed??

Comment: @markackerman8-gmail.com When I tested `sudo fwts aspm` all the tests passed and none of the tests failed, however I also got the verbose results of each test by running the command `cat results.log` all of which I added to my answer. Test 1 is the PCIe ASPM ACPI test.

Answer (score 2):

I just answered my own Question ... I hope it helps others.

After the above 2 suggested (and these first 2 commands explained and restated for some good definitions and clarity):

I will state how to view the log file easy-peasy

Install: Firmware Test Suite (FWTS) is a test suite that performs sanity checks on firmware. It is intended to identify BIOS, UEFI, ACPI and many other errors and if appropriate it will try to explain the errors and give advice to help workaround or fix firmware bugs.with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install fwts
```

Run the check:

```
sudo fwts aspm
```

And to check the log of this "Check"

```
cat results.log
```

I hope this new bit of info helps other!

Mark

Comment: I was so busy answering your comment below my answer that I didn't notice that I independently got the same results that you did 15 minutes after you posted your answer. I also learned that the link in my answer was broken, so I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem at boot and managed to solve following [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052971/r8168-r8169-realtek-driver-module-troubles):

`$ wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.047.02-1_all.deb`

`$ sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.047.02-1_all.deb`

`$ sudo rmmod r8169`

`$ sudo echo "blacklist r8169" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

then reboot.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at boot on Ubuntu 22.04 after playing around in the BIOS,and managed to solve.

1. Removed the realtek and r8169 modules with rmmod.
2. Tried to install a deb package for r8168 and failed due to strange dependencies.
3. Tried to apt install r8168-dkms, also failed.

Decided to go back to 8169, but this process somehow completely removed realtek and r8169 from loading on boot. So this is the workaround

4. sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/5.19.0-43-
   generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/realtek.ko

   sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/5.19.0-43-
   generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169.ko
5. Add the realtek and r8169 modules to /etc/modules

Lucky me it worked. Hope this helps!