# iwlwifi: Wireless issue: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

When in my browser scrolling through a web page it freezes in 4 second intervals, not for very long but it is an annoyance. This also happens when I stream videos although the sound doesn't get effected (First i thought it was only the video that was the issue - then I realized it happening while browsing)

```
sudo lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial


dmesg | grep iwlwifi

[   37.756102] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   38.069472] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   39.158747] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   39.158750] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   39.158751] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   39.158753] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2200 BGN, REV=0x104
[   39.158848] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   39.398141] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   54.727546] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   54.735150] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   54.735237] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[   54.980516] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   54.988136] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   54.988222] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0


lspci | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)
```

I have tried what was suggested by [What does "r8169: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control" really mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372363/what-does-r8169-cant-disable-aspm-os-doesnt-have-aspm-control-really-mean)

```
sudo fwts aspm

Running 1 tests, results appended to results.log
Test: PCIe ASPM test.                                                       
  PCIe ASPM ACPI test.                                                         
  PCIe ASPM registers test.                               2 passed, 1 failed, 7 warnings
```

I have looked at results.log:

```
aspm: PCIe ASPM test.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 2: PCIe ASPM ACPI test.
FADT X_FIRMWARE_CTRL 64 bit pointer was zero, falling back to using
FIRMWARE_CTRL 32 bit pointer.
PCIe ASPM is controlled by Linux kernel.

Test 2 of 2: PCIe ASPM registers test.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:01h.00h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 01h:00h.00h L0s not enabled.

ADVICE: The ASPM L0s low power Link state is optimized for short entry and exit
latencies, while providing substantial power savings. Disabling L0s of a PCIe
device may increases power consumption, and will impact the battery life of a
mobile system.

PASSED: Test 2, PCIe ASPM setting matched was matched.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.01h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.01h L1 not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 03h:00h.00h L1 not enabled.

ADVICE: The ASPM L0s low power Link state is optimized for short entry and exit
latencies, while providing substantial power savings. Disabling L0s of a PCIe
device may increases power consumption, and will impact the battery life of a
mobile system.


ADVICE: The ASPM L1 low power Link state is optimized for maximum power savings
with longer entry and exit latencies. Disabling L1 of a PCIe device may
increases power consumption, and will impact the battery life of a mobile system
significantly.

FAILED [MEDIUM] PCIEASPM_Unmatched: Test 2, PCIe ASPM setting was not matched.
RP 00h:1Ch.01h has ASPM = 00h.
Device 03h:00h.00h has ASPM = 01h.

ADVICE: ASPM control registers between root port and device must match in order
for ASPM to be active. Unmatched configuration indicates software did not
configure ASPM correctly and the system is not saving power at its full
potential.

WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.02h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 04h:00h.00h L0s not enabled.

ADVICE: The ASPM L0s low power Link state is optimized for short entry and exit
latencies, while providing substantial power savings. Disabling L0s of a PCIe
device may increases power consumption, and will impact the battery life of a
mobile system.

PASSED: Test 2, PCIe ASPM setting matched was matched.

================================================================================
2 passed, 1 failed, 7 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
================================================================================


2 passed, 1 failed, 7 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.

Test Failure Summary
================================================================================

Critical failures: NONE

High failures: NONE

Medium failures: 1
 aspm: PCIe ASPM setting was not matched.

Low failures: NONE

Other failures: NONE

Test           |Pass |Fail |Abort|Warn |Skip |Info |
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
aspm           |    2|    1|     |    7|     |     |
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
Total:         |    2|    1|    0|    7|    0|    0|
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Regrettably this is where I am stuck, I can't seem to find the aspm wiki that is referred in the question that got me this far. Any further direction or assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, however I noticed under Kubuntu 18.04 LTS the exactly same "can't disable ASPM" message in conjunction with an older Intel WiFi Link 5100 network card.

The solution was to **enforce** the enabling of the PCIE ASPM functionality. This can be easily done by adding the **"pcie_aspm=force"** parameter to the **GRUB config**.

More information can be found here:
[How do I add pcie_aspm=force to my boot options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68372/how-do-i-add-pcie-aspm-force-to-my-boot-options)

This topic can be regarded as a typical BIOS & Linux difficulty. The BIOS is telling Linux that ASPM is NOT available. Nevertheless ASPM is available, activated and used by the Intel WiFi Link 5100.

It is really difficult to recognize any logical concept behind that type of BIOS programming... ;-)