# 'no wifi adapter found' Broadcom wifi driver problem

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I have a very old Dell Vostro 1015 laptop, and just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on it. The problem is that I cannot use wifi, in the wifi settings it says "no wifi adapter found" (the bluetooth has the same issue). The internet works with ethernet cable though.

I did extensive research here in the forum but none of the solution options worked, I suppose each case is specific:) Therefore I run the wireless-info script command, please see the result in the linked Ubuntu Pastebin site[wireless-info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b5ndm9rHyr/)

What I've done? I've tried to update the system, nothing; to restart the network manager, nothing; and to install the most up-to-date driver for my wifi adapter according to this
[r8168/r8169 RealTek driver module troubles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052971/r8168-r8169-realtek-driver-module-troubles)
nothing. Please, help me! thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: r8168/r8169 is a wired adapter and has nothing to do with wifi.

Comment: Your wireless adapter is `Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r8169` is a wired Ethernet adapter and is not related to Wi-Fi.

You can install firmware for your Broadcom wireless adapter by

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and Wi-Fi should work.

I suggest removing `r8168-dkms` driver. It may cause problems on kernel upates and it is not needed at all.

Comment: Thank you, Pilot6, it is working now, I did exactly what you have said. Thank you!