# How do I remove the limit from my eth connection in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, ethernet, connection

I have a dual boot set up with Ubuntu 18.04 and 22.04. When I log in 18.04 the wired connection in the network settings shows a Link speed of 1000 Mb/s, while in 22.04 it shows 100 Mb/s.

Info on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
> uname -a

Linux cc 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


> sudo lshw -C network

  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 01
       serial: d0:37:45:4c:0f:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:79 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcb00000-fcb03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: 04:d9:f5:76:15:b0
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:39 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fca04000-fca04fff memory:fca00000-fca03fff

 
> sudo ethtool enp8s0

Settings for enp8s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    master-slave cfg: preferred slave
    master-slave status: slave
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: yes


> sudo ethtool -i enp8s0

version: 5.19.0-35-generic
firmware-version: rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:08:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no


> lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %

07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. PRIME B450M-A Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169


> sudo dmesg | grep r8169 # the up and down links are me setting the speed to 1000 and 100

[    1.021751] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, 04:d9:f5:76:15:b0, XID 541, IRQ 54
[    1.021756] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    2.775004] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: renamed from eth0
[    5.878614] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-800:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-800:00, irq=MAC)
[    6.066748] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[   22.934280] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-800:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
[   22.934294] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control rx/tx
[  298.818969] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[  325.940383] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[  344.602188] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-800:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
[  344.602201] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control rx/tx
[  892.022066] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1021.829180] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1033.732636] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1070.106381] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1082.716879] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1085.513138] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 1485.561946] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1587.331448] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1590.190212] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 1674.111292] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1843.666686] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 1846.453070] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 2403.530799] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 2439.863622] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 2442.743673] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 2453.224431] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 2457.465233] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 2550.292449] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 2553.750133] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 2602.361706] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 2692.932207] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[ 2695.792083] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx


> ip link | grep enpip # on speed 100

2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

I already tried running `sudo ethtool -s enp8s0 speed 1000 autoneg off duplex full`, but it kills my connection when I do so.

```
> sudo ethtool enp8s0 # on speed 1000

Settings for enp8s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: off
    master-slave cfg: preferred slave
    master-slave status: unknown
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: no


> ip link | grep enp # on speed 1000

2: enp8s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

My connection only comes back when I set the speed to 100 using `ethtool -s`.
I'm ruling out hardware problems because the link works at 1000 Mb/s in the same machine when I boot in Ubuntu 18.04.

How can I make it run at 1000 Mb/s in Ubuntu 22.04?

---

###### Edit:

I ran:

```
> sudo apt install r8168-dkms
> sudo rmmod r8169
rmmod: ERROR: Module r8169 is not currently loaded

>echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist r8169
```

And performed a hard power cycle. These are the differences in the logs (basically just changed a few places from `r8169` to `r8168`) but the problem persists:

```
> sudo lshw -C network

  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 01
       serial: d0:37:45:4c:0f:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:79 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcb00000-fcb03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: 04:d9:f5:76:15:b0
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.049.02-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fca04000-fca04fff memory:fca00000-fca03fff


> sudo ethtool enp8s0

Settings for enp8s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes


> sudo ethtool -i enp8s0

driver: r8168
version: 8.049.02-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:08:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no


> lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %

07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. PRIME B450M-A Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168


> sudo ethtool enp8s0 # on speed 1000

Settings for enp8s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
```

Comment: Install the `r8168` driver into 22.04.  The `r8169` driver is really flaky on the `RTL8111/8168/8411` chipset.  `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`

Comment: @Terrance, I was able to set `sudo ethtool -s enp8s0 speed 1000 autoneg on duplex full` now (when I used `autoneg off` it returned `Invalid argument`). But now I get `r8168: enp8s0: link up`  `r8168: enp8s0: link down` every minute on `sudo dmesg`. Connection keeps dropping. Works normally in `speed 100` though.

Comment: My bad!  Use this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1164639/231142 and blacklist the r8169 driver.  I forgot to tell you that and you are probably having a driver conflict right now.  No need to install the driver from that answer.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that didn't work.
When I ran `sudo rmmod r8169`, I got `rmmod: ERROR: Module r8169 is not currently loaded`.
I added it to the blacklist anyways, but the link keeps dropping. When I set it to speed 1000, `sudo dmesg` still returns `r8168: enp8s0: link down`  `r8168: enp8s0: link up`  `r8168: enp8s0: link down`  `r8168: enp8s0: link up` ...

Comment: Oh, perform a hard power cycle of the system.  Power off the host, disconnect all power.  Hold in the power button for 15-30 seconds.  Reconnect all power and power the host back on.  Did you run the part of blacklisting the driver?  `echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`  I have had to do this power cycle of my host where the r8169 driver hung on causing issues to the point of a simple reboot would not fix the issue.

Comment: @Terrance, again thanks for the support, but sadly it didn't work. I did blacklist the driver and performed a hard power cycle. The problem is still there unfortunately.

Comment: Last thing I would suggest would be possibly to back the 22.04 LTS to Kernel version 5.15.  It seems that the 5.19 Kernel just has too many issues.  I have gone back to the 5.15 for now and seems to have taken care of issues I was having in 22.04 LTS.  Beyond that, I don't know what else to tell you other than possibly clean installing 22.04 LTS.  `sudo apt install linux-headers-5.15.0-69 linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic linux-image-5.15.0-69-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-69-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-69-generic`

Comment: @Terrance, I did try downgrading the kernel but it didn't work. I tried versions 5.15 and 5.13. 5.4 (which is the same in my ubuntu 18 didn't run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did manage to solve it by following these steps in this exact order using 5.19 kernel:

1. Download "GBE Ethernet LINUX driver r8168 for kernel up to 5.19" from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software
2. Extract it and run the `autorun.sh` file as `sudo`
3. Restart the computer
4. Run `sudo ethtool -s enp8s0 speed 1000 autoneg on duplex full`
5. Unplug the Ethernet cable and replug it

I'm not sure which of these steps were or weren't necessary, but now it looks like it's working.

---

###### Edit

I also followed https://askubuntu.com/a/1334101/231142 as suggested by @Terrance in the comments.

Comment: That is strange!  The 8.051.02 RTL driver will actually fail on my system, but the RTL8168 8.049.02 from the repos will work fine in both 5.19 and 5.15.  I am glad that you got it working!  +1  But, I will suggest that you look at https://askubuntu.com/a/1334101/231142 and change the version number to match the one you downloaded which is the 8.051.02, that way when Kernel updates happen DKMS will install the driver automatically into the new update.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks! Just did that. Now `dkms status` shows `r8168/8.049.02, 5.19.0-35-generic, x86_64: built` `r8168/8.051.02, 5.19.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed`.

Comment: You can remove the 8.049.02 driver from that kernel.  `sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed in the latest updates for Ubuntu 22.04. I've just installed kernel 5.19.0-38 and that has brought the speed back to 1 GB on my r8168. Tested transferring files to a memory card, seeing up to 500 Mb speeds (HD read speed limited).

Comment: The answer does not need to contain the network description. This is info that a question would contain.