# Ubuntu 18.04 installation on Asus D553M

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, asus

I have an Asus D553M notebook that came bundled with Windows 8. I used GParted to clear the whole hard disk of the previous Windows files. I want to Install Ubuntu 18.04 as the only operating system.

This I have tried to no avail. I tried installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but the system freezes and shows a black screen after I select *Install Ubuntu* or *Try Ubuntu without Installing*. I tried changing  nomodeset to 0, disabling the splash screen but the installation fails at `can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control` .

I also tried booting using the Legacy BIOS (with CSM disabled), and even after disabling nomodeset and ahcpi, the screen freezes.

[image]

Comment: Can you go into tty mode by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3? Try logging in and installing [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/372387/816190). Also, which graphic card your pc is having?

Comment: I haven't been able to install the Ubuntu OS, so for now I can't access tty but I can access the grub terminal by pressing "e" on the first Installation screen. I think the graphics card should be Intel HD Graphics. Thank you.